# Node.js - Expressjs middleware to extend res.render

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I'd like to know if there is a built in way to extend Express.js's res.render function because, I'd like to pass a default set of "locals" to every template that is rendered. Currently I've written a small middleware that uses underscore.js's extend function to merge the default "locals" and the ones specific for that template:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.render2 = function (view, locals, fn) {
        res.render(view, _.extend(settings.template_defaults, locals), fn);
    };
    next();
});
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`app.locals`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.locals) is likely what you're looking for:

```
app.locals(settings.template_defaults);
```

Along with [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.locals) and [`res.render`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.render), Express is already capable of merging the values for you:

```
// locals for all views in the application
app.locals(settings.template_defaults);

// middleware for common locals with request-specific values
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals({
        // e.g. session: req.session
    });
    next();
});

// and locals specific to the route
app.get('...', function (req, res) {
    res.render('...', {
        // ...
    });
});
```

Comment: It's `res.locals`, though link is okay (can't edit 1 symbol).

Answer (score 3):

```
res.locals or app.locals is for this exact purpose.
```